# Pattern-matching returning a string representation of math expression

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have to write a function dump which takes an expression

```
type expression = 
| Int of int
| Float of float
| Add of expression * expression
| Sub of expression * expression
| Mult of expression * expression
| Div of expression * expression
;;
```

and returns a string representation of it.
For example:

```
dump (Add (Int 1, Int 2));;
dump (Mult (Int 5, Add(Int 2, Int 3)), Int 1)
```

should return respectively

```
- : string = "1+2"
- : string = "5*(2+3)-1"
```

I've written something like this:

```
let rec dump e = match e with
    | Int a -> string_of_int a
    | Float a -> string_of_float a
    | Add (e1,e2) -> "(" ^ (dump e1) ^ "+" ^ (dump e2) ^ ")"
    | Sub (e1,e2) -> "(" ^ (dump e1) ^ "-" ^ (dump e2) ^ ")"
    | Mult (e1,e2) -> (dump e1) ^ "*" ^ (dump e2)
    | Div (e1,e2) -> (dump e1) ^ "/" ^ (dump e2)
;;
```

and returned expressions are correct, but still not optimal.
(for Add (Int 1, Int 2)) it is (1+2) and should be 1+2 ). How can I fix this?
(without nested pattern matching which isn't a good idea)

Comment: Anything wrong with wrapping `dump` with a `pretty_dump` that calls `dump` and strips outer parens?

Comment: @delnan: This would still yield `"1 + (2 + (3 + 4)))"` for `Add(Int 1, Add(Int 2, Add (Int 3, Int 4)))` while I assume he wants `"1 + 2 + 3 + 4"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, define a list of priority levels for your operators:

```
module Prio = struct
  let div = 4
  let mul = 3
  let sub = 2
  let add = 1
end
```

An useful construct is "wrap in brackets if this condition is true" :

```
let wrap_if c str = if c then "("^str^")" else str
```

Finally, define an auxiliary printing function which is provided with a "priority" argument meaning "by the way, you're wrapped in an expression which has priority X, so protect your output accordingly":

```
let dump e = 
  let rec aux prio = function
    | Int a -> string_of_int a
    | Float a -> string_of_float a
    | Add (e1,e2) -> 
        wrap_if (prio > Prio.add) (aux Prio.add e1 ^ "+" ^ aux Prio.add e2)
    | Sub (e1,e2) -> 
        wrap_if (prio > Prio.add) (aux Prio.add e1 ^ "-" ^ aux Prio.sub e2)
    | Mult (e1,e2) -> 
        wrap_if (prio > Prio.mul) (aux Prio.mul e1 ^ "*" ^ aux Prio.mul e2)
    | Div (e1,e2) -> 
        wrap_if (prio > Prio.mul) (aux Prio.mul e1 ^ "/" ^ aux Prio.div e2)
  in aux Prio.add e
;;
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's think about when you need parens:

First of all always wrapping parens around certain operations is the wrong approach. Whether a term needs to be parenthesized or not does not only depend on which operator is used in the term, but also which operator the term is an operand to.

E.g. when `1+2` and `3+4` are operands to `+`, it should be `1+2+3+4` - no parens. However if the operator is `*`, it needs to be `(1+2) * (3+4)`.

So for which combinations of operators do we need parens?

The operands to `+` never need to be parenthesized. If the operands are products or quotients, they have higher precedence anyway, and if the operands are differences, you need no parens because `x + (y - z) = x + y -z`.

With `-` it's a bit different. `*` and `/` still don't need to be parenthesized because they have higher precedence, but `+` and `-` do iff they're in the second operand because `x + y - z = (x + y) - z`, but `x - y + z != x - (y + z)`.

With Mult both operands need to be parenthesized if they're Add or Sub, but not if they're Mult or Div.

With Div the first operand needs to be parenthesized if it's Add or Sub and the second always needs to be parenthesized (unless it's an Int or Float, of course).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you want to build some set of reduction rules which can be applied to yield the "prettified" or most-reduced form of your expressions, based on order of operations and e.g. commutativity, associativity, etc. For instance `(a + a) => a + a`, `(a * b) + c => a * b + c` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

A rather simple and yet rather generic answer (works for other syntaxes than mathematical expressions) : pick precedences (and, if you're picky, associativities) for your constructors, and only add parentheses when a subterm constructor has lower precedence than the current constructor.

More precisely : when you want to print a constructor `C(x1,x2,x3..)`, you look at the head constructor of each `xi` (if `x1` is `D(y1,y2..)`, its head constructor is `D`), compare the precedence levels of `C` and `D`. If the precendence of `D` is lower, you add parenthesis around the string representation of `x2`.

Comment: If you just do this, `Sub( Int 42, Add(Int 23, Int 13))` is printed as `42 - 23 + 13`, which is wrong. Unless you give `Sub` lower precedence than `Add`, in which case you'll end up with more parens than you want to.

Comment: I don't think a good solution to the pretty-printing problem needs to be perfect, in that it exactly minimizes the parenthesis. Solving the printing problem perfectly is (I think) equivalent to solving the parsing problem, and that is indeed quite complex. For parsing we have tools solving the problem for us, but pretty-printing is generally a hand-written task; or at leat I do not know of "printer generators" with fine support for associativity, precendence and all that.

Comment: Therefore, I think an approximate solution is good if it is a good compromise between quality of the output and simplicity of the code. My solution is quite simple to implement (only marginally more difficult than the paranoid parenthesis-everywhere solution) and produces good result.

Comment: Finally, I'd like to point out that the associativity/precendence issues tends to be concentrated on mathematical expressions. The structured syntaxes in general tend to have a lesser degree of implicit conflict resolution, which makes this solution quite efficient for the general problem of printing arbitrary syntaxic terms, even if seems weak on mathematical expressions.